# Why is window.navigator.storage.estimate() sometimes undefined on Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, local-storage

If I serve my app from http://localhost, in the dev console I can do `window.navigator.storage.estimate()`.

If I serve the same app from http://example.com where `example.com` resolves to 127.0.0.1 from my /etc/hosts, `window.navigator` is undefined.

How come?

(Chrome is 71)

Comment: `This feature is available only in secure contexts`  But maybe its ok for  localhost as that's commonly used for dev purposes.

Comment: @Keith You're right. On digging I found that Chrome considers http://localhost to be a secure context. Feel free to post this as an answer.

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58349734/why-is-navigator-storage-undefined-in-latest-chrome/66970829#66970829

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From MDN -> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/StorageEstimate/quota

It appears this feature is only available in a secure context, aka  https://

But it appears Chrome considers localhost to also be a secure context, so https:// is not required.  I assume this is because localhost is commonly used for development purposes, and acquiring an SSL cert for local domains can be tricky.

More info at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Secure_Contexts which confirms `file://` and `localhost` to be considered secure.  `if (window.isSecureContext)` is available to test the status.