# Why is navigator.storage undefined in latest Chrome?

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage, navigator

I'm trying to use `navigator.storage` on `http://0.0.0.0:5000` while developing locally, but `navigator.storage` is `undefined`.

When/why can `navigator.storage` be undefined?

I'm in Chrome 77.

Comment: It's defined for me on 77.0.3865.120, Win 10, what's your version?

Comment: From the docs: _This feature is available only in secure contexts (HTTPS), in some or all supporting browsers._ Are you using HTTPS on your localhost?

Comment: @KostasX Aaah, I am not using HTTPS on localhost. Maybe that's it.

Comment: None HTTPS seems to return in Chrome for me,.. But `http://0.0.0.0:5000` is not a real address anyway.   Did you mean to do `http://127.0.0.1:5000` instead for localhost.

Comment: Localhost is a secure context even without HTTPS, but you have to use (and should be using) `http://127.0.0.1:5000/` = `http://localhost:5000/`.

Comment: @Ry- Thanks, that indeed is the answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per @Ry-'s comment, using `http://localhost:5000` or `http://127.0.0.1:5000` instead of `http://0.0.0.0:5000` does the trick.

For some reason the browser decides to make `navigator.storage` unavailable when visiting a URL on `http://0.0.0.0`.

Answer (score 0):

I was simply not resolving the promise properly in the Chrome console:

```
await navigator.storage.estimate()
```

Comment: You can just do `await navigator.storage.estimate()`. No need for an extra promise because `estimate()` already returns a promise.