# How to use StorageManager in Angular with dexie to prevent accidentally deletion of indexeddb

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, indexeddb, dexie

In my Angular project I have used dexie to handle indexeddb. But somehow all data gets deleted accidentally (you can say indexeddb crash). I want to use StorageManger in Angular with dexie so that I can prevent accidentally deletion.

> https://dexie.org/docs/StorageManager

I tried to use the example from above but seems like it is not working. As there is no properties like storage or storage.persisted or any function with navigator.

Or any other way you guys can suggest to prevent this behaviour.

Comment: What browser are you using? Can you open devtools console and write navigator.storage or navigator.storage.persist and see what it resolves to?

Comment: I use Google Chrome. writing `navigator.storage` in console, it shows undefined.

Comment: Also tried with `Navigation.storage`, it shows undefined too.

Comment: What version of Chrome? Even incognito mode has navigator.storage available.

Comment: I have a chrome Version 122.0.6261.94

Comment: What is the URL of the page you are visiting? It might be that chrome hides navitator.storage when the protocol is not https (with the exception of `http://localhost` which is ok but not `http://somethingelse`).

This ticket is targeting the same issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58349734/why-is-navigator-storage-undefined-in-latest-chrome

Comment: I tried `await navigator.storage.estimate()` on production server, it worked and showed me that result. I also tried `await navigator.storage.persist()` and it worked too and gave me result true.
But when I see indexeddb it is still showing me `is persistent  No`. My main issue is to make it persistent yes/true, so that is should not delete the indexeddb automatically, that is the reason I want trying to use storageManager.